# Bidirectional Connection In WCF

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, reference

I am creating a simple notification program and I am using WCF For that.
In This Program two User Connect to each other using IP Address.
when they connected,if each user filled a textbox and pressed enter,other user will notify.

To do this I have two Projects A And B In a Solution(Server & Client),I made the connection from A to B successfully.

To do that I Added the reference of B into A.

Now I Want Want to do this For connection from B to A.But when i want to add reference of A to But I  get

Circular Reference error  .

Comment: What you're looking for is WCF Duplex. Google it and come back if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you must decide if multiple clients would need to connect to your program running on the server. If so, you must add a service reference or create a proxy for your client application. If you want your server to "push" messages to your client application/s, you must register a `callback` from the client to your WCF service. Please read through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) link for more information on WCF callbacks.